# Script to show number of files (by file type) in a directory?

Tags: shell-script, filenames, sort

I want to show this kind of statistics about a particular directory:

```
$ myscript.sh
.c 34265 files
.h 17866 files
.cbl 1804 files
.pco 389 files
[...]
```

Is there a tool that can do this?

Here is my attempt:

```
find . -name "*.*" | sed -e "s/.*\.//g" | sort -u
```

And then I could type for each type `find . -name "*.pc" | wc -l` but it is bothersome so I wrote:

```
find . -name "*.*" | sed -e "s/.*\.//g" | sort -u |\
    xargs find . -name "*.{}" | wc -l
```

Unfortunately I must be missing something because it says:

```
find: paths must precede expression: as
```

("as" is the first extension)
Any idea what is going wrong?
Is there already a tool that does what I want (a tool counting file lines would be OK too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `gawk`: pipe your list of filenames through the following (left as an exercise/I tested with `ls -1`, but Don't Parse `ls`(tm)):

```
gawk -F. '1 {exts[$NF]++} END {for (ext in exts){printf "%s: %s files\n", ext, exts[ext]}}'
```

This assumes that everything that is followed by a period is not part of the extension, so filenames without period count as all-extension. (I think it should be sufficient to change `1 {` to `(NF>1) {` to only get files with extensions proper.

Comment: That works! Here is the complete command: `find . -name "*.*" | gawk -F. '(NF>1) {exts[$NF]++} END {for (ext in exts){printf "%s: %s files\n", ext, exts[ext]}}'`

Answer (score 1):

The following pipeline prints each distinct line in the input preceded by its repeat count, sorted by decreasing repeat count:

```
sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Thus:

```
find . -type f -name '?*.*' | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | awk -F. '{if(NF>1)arr[$NF]++;else blnk++}END{for(i in arr)printf(".%s %s file(s)\n",i,arr[i]);printf("<No Extension> %s file(s)\n",blnk)}'
```

Comment: Using  `ls` is typically not a good idea (ie. it is a *bad* idea). eg. it prints a line in which the link's target's extension is returned. So the `awk` filter reports on the wrong extension.. It will also pick up directory names which have a *dot* in their names.. Aside from the mentioned *and other* complications caused by `ls`, I like the awk logic..  (and it appears that he wants the output sorted by the number of occurrences)